# Access VBA Form_before_update event is unnecessarily triggered

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have this code (in Form_Before_update Event) which checks for duplicate values in sdtCode field:

```
If DCount("[sdtCode]", "[tbl_sdt_Info]", "[sdtCode] = '" & Me.sdtCode.Value & "'") > 0 Then
 Me.Undo
 MsgBox "duplicates found"
End If
```

It works perfectly. However, after I use the following code to link the record to a picture, and when I try to move to another record the fisrst code is triggered and it gives me the "duplicates found" message!!!!

```
Private Sub sdtPicture_Click()
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim i As Integer
Dim strSelectedPicture As Variant
Dim strExtension As String

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)

    With fd
        .AllowMultiSelect = False
        
        'show only set of extension file in dialog
        .Filters.Clear
        .Filters.Add "Image file", "*.jpeg;*.png;*.jpg;*.gif", 1
        
        If .Show = -1 Then
            For Each strSelectedPicture In .SelectedItems
                For i = Len(strSelectedPicture) To 1 Step -1
                If Mid(strSelectedPicture, i, 1) = "." Then
                    strExtension = Mid(strSelectedPicture, i)
                    Exit For
                End If
            Next i
            
            Me.sdtImagePath.Value = strSelectedPicture
            
            ' if folder name doesnt exist then make new one
            On Error Resume Next
            MkDir "C:\dbImageArchive\students\"
            
'            On Error GoTo 0
            
            'if folder exist, copy image to distination folder
            'file name in the drive C:\
            FileCopy strSelectedPicture, "C:\dbImageArchive\students\" & "sdt_" & Me.sdtCode & strExtension
            Me.sdtPicturePath.Value = "C:\dbImageArchive\students\" & "sdt_" & Me.sdtCode.Value & strExtension
            
            'Add a text box (sdtPictureName) to display the name of the picture file
            'Me.sdtPictureName = Me.sdtID & strExtension
            Next strSelectedPicture
            Else
            'display when no file is selected
            MsgBox "?? E?II ???C?", vbInformation, ""
        End If
        
        Set fd = Nothing
    End With
    
    Me.cboOrganizations.SetFocus
'Me.Refresh
End Sub
```

I tried the Form_after_update event. It produced further problems. Any ideas to solve this issue please. Thank you.

Comment: this is not a SQL question, looks like VB?

Comment: my mistake, sorry

Comment: If you want BeforeUpdate event to check for duplicate and then abort record commitment, need more than Undo. Use the event Cancel argument. How is the sdtCode field populated? Could use its BeforeUpdate event to validate input. Somehow your form is committing record then code to add image is creating another record with the same sdtCode. Might want to post in a forum that allows attaching files and provide your db for analysis.

Comment: I tried putting the validation code in sdtCode BeforeUpdate event. And It worked perfectly. Thank you very much pal!